# Sensu Emailer `parse_options': invalid option: -j (OptionParser::InvalidOption)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sensu

Trying to setup amazon ses for sensu

**Setup 1**
I have

> handler-mailer.rb -j mailme_using_amazonses
>   in my config.json

and `handler-mailer.rb` is in my `/etc/sensu/plugins` folder

When I run on command line, I get errors

```
ruby /etc/sensu/plugins/handler-mailer.rb -j mailme_using_amazonses
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-cli-1.7.0/lib/mixlib/cli.rb:230:in `parse_options': invalid option: -j (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.3/lib/sensu-handler.rb:18:in `initialize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.3/lib/sensu-handler.rb:78:in `new'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.3/lib/sensu-handler.rb:78:in `block in <class:Handler>'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- erubis (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /etc/sensu/plugins/handler-mailer.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

My mailme_using_amazonses has the following

```
{
    "handlers": {
        "mailer-ses": {
           "mail_from": "from@example.com",
           "mail_to": "to@example.com",
           "use_ami_role": true,
           "secret_key": "MyKey",
           "access_key": "MyAccess",
           "region": "us-west-2"
        }
    }
}
```

**Setup 2**
In `config.json` I have the following

```
{
.. other config ..
 "handlers": {
    "handler-ses": {  **HERE I ALSO TRIED "ses"**
      "mail_from": "from@example.com",
      "mail_to": "to@example.com",
      "use_ami_role": true,
      "access_key": "accesskey",
      "secret_key": "secretekey",
      "region": "us-west-2",
      "subscriptions": {
        "subscription_name": {
          "mail_to": "teamemail@example.com"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I restart `sensu-server` I get the following error

```
configuration is invalid
{
  "errors":[
    {
      "object":{
        "mail_from":"from@example.com",
        "mail_to":"to@example.com",
        "use_ami_role":true,
        "access_key":"accesskey",
        "secret_key":"secretkey",
        "region":"us-west-2",
        "subscriptions":{
          "subscription_name":{
            "mail_to":"teamemail@example.com"
          }
        },
        "name":"handler-ses"
      },
      "message":"handler type must be a string"
    },
    {
      "object":{
        "mail_from":"from@example.com",
        "mail_to":"to@example.com",
        "use_ami_role":true,
        "access_key":"accesskey",
        "secret_key":"secretkey",
        "region":"us-west-2",
        "subscriptions":{
          "subscription_name":{
            "mail_to":"teamemail@example.com"
          }
        },
        "name":"handler-ses"
      },
      "message":"unknown handler type"
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I read the `handler-ses.rb` file. Here it was noted that the config should be in `ses.json`. I copied the **Setup 2** ses configuration from `config.json` json into `ses.json` and placed it under `/etc/sensu/handers` folder. The error went away. I am yet to get the emails though.

Will update this answer after I get `ses` email working.